# Adding an array to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to have a numpy array that looks something like this:

```
X = np.array([[10, 20], [20, 25], [30, 16], [40, 18], [50, 90], [60, 87]])
```

I currently have dictionary values that I retrieve from firestore:

```
doc_ref = db.collection('CPU Logs')
query_ref = doc_ref.where(u'testData', u'==', True).order_by(u'logId')
docs = query_ref.get()
```

I loop through them and assign the key values to 2 variables, `id` and `usage`, before adding them to an array `toAppend`:

```
for doc in docs:
    values = doc.to_dict()
    id = values['logId']
    usage = values['usage']
    toAppend = [id, usage]
```

toAppend would look something like `[10, 30]` if the id were 10 and the usage were 30. Now, I'm having trouble trying to add it to an empty numpy array. I've tried inserting:

```
X = np.array([])
for doc in docs:
    values = doc.to_dict()
    id = values['logId']
    usage = values['usage']
    toAppend = [id, usage]
    a = X.flatten()
    np.insert(a, [0,0], toAppend)

print(X)
```

as well as appending:

```
np.append(X, toAppend)
```

But both don't seem to work, as the print statement just prints out `[]`.

Comment: Those methods **return** the array with the appended object, therefore you should write `result = np.insert(a, [0,0], toAppend)` as explained [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html).

Comment: List append works in-place; `np.append` is a poorly named imitation, that gives many users problems.  `np.array` and `np.concatenate` (and the `stack` variants) all take a list of arrays.  Use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [the docs for `insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) and [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatten.html): They both return new arrays (copies). So you need to write

```
X = np.insert(a, [0, 0], toAppend)
```

in order for `X` to contain the extended array. I also don't think you need the preceding `X.flatten()`.

Instead of inserting into a numpy array (which is expensive), you should consider just building a nested `list` and only convert it once at the end.