# Appending to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
result = np.zeros((samples,), dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('data', '<f8', (datalen,))])
```

I would like to create variable `tempresult` that accumulates the data `result`, and once I have accumulated 25000 samples, I would like to perform some operation on it.

So I would like to do something like:

```
result = np.zeros((samples,), dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('data', '<f8', (datalen,))])

tempresult.append(result)

if ( len(tempresult[0]  > 25000 )):
   # do something
```

I tried the answer code but I get exception TypeError: invalid type promotion

```
result = np.zeros((samples,), dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('data', '<f8', (datalen,))])

        if self.storeTimeStamp:
            self.storeTimeStamp = False
            self.timestamp = message.timestamp64
            self.oldsamples = 0

        for sample in range(0, samples):
            sstep = self.timestamp + (self.oldsamples + sample) * step
            result[sample] = (sstep, data[sample])

        self.oldsamples = self.oldsamples + samples


        # append
        np.append(self.tempresult, result)

        if len(self.tempresult) < 25000:
            return
        return [self.tempresult]
```

Comment: If you are appending to `self.tempresult`, then `len(self.tempresult)` is what is increasing each time you do so.  `len(self.tempresult[0])` won't change (assuming that it's valid at all), and `len(self.tempresult[0]  > 25000 )` is just meaningless, you're asking for the length of a comparison result.

Comment: @jasonharper how would I initalize self.tempresult ? to None ?

Comment: Do not use `np.append` without first reading and understanding its python code.

Comment: Why aren't you using list append? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51665905/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) read `np.append` docs.

```
np.append(self.tempresult, result)
```

is wrong.  `np.append` returns a new array; it does not act in place like list append.

2) `np.append` is a clumsy interface to `np.concatenate`.  If you don't understand `concatenate`, you'll get messed up by `append`.

3) because it makes a new array each time, repeated concatenate is slow.  It's much faster to collect a list of arrays, and do one concatenate at the end

4) when using a compound `dtype`, all inputs to `concatenate` have to have the same `dtype`.