# How to concatenate numpy arrays to other arrays python?

Tags: python, arrays

I want the 3d array to be empty in the beginning and then append an array to index 0 and then append an array to that array.

```
paths = np.array([], ndmin=3)
print(paths)
print(paths.ndim)

paths = np.append(paths, [])
print(paths)

paths[0] = np.append(paths[0], [3,4,5])
print(paths)
```

output

```
[]
3
[]
paths[0] = np.append(paths[0], [3,4,5])
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: How do you expect the array to look after the operation?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "add"? Do you mean concatenate, or mathematical addition?

Comment: @FCo concatenate / append

Comment: @DmitriChubarov [ [ [3,4,5] ] ]

Comment: Do you know the size of the array upfront? It is much faster to allocate memory and then just assign to slices of the array than to concatenate if you're doing it many times, because concatenation requires the entire array to be copied to new memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an array to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665905/adding-an-array-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I dont really know what you mean by size. The array should be able to go from`[]` to `[ [ [3,4,5] ] ]` to `[ [ [3,4,5], [3,4,5] ], [ [3,4,5], [3,4,5] ] ]`

Comment: @monopoly_lover I mean that if you know the final shape that the array needs to be (e.g. `[]` is `(0,)`, `[[[3,4,5]]]` is `(1, 1, 3)`, and `[[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]], [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]]` is `(2, 2, 3)`. If this is the final result you want, then it's faster to do `a = np.zeros((2,2,3))` and then assign `a[0, 0, :] = [3, 4, 5]; a[1, 0, :] = [3, 4, 5]` and so on

Comment: Right.  Start out with `paths = np.zeros((1,1,3)`, then `p[0,0] = [3,4,5]`.  Appending is not a terribly efficient way to build up np arrays.